# Cygwin nano syntax highlighting

Tags: cygwin, syntax-highlighting, nano

I want to have basic syntax highlighting in a cygwin implementation of nano.

[This comment](https://superuser.com/questions/194970/a-linux-version-of-cygwin#comment197841_194970) confirms for me that it's possible, but I can't find any information on how to actually make it happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin will include many `*.nanorc` files in `/usr/share/nano/`. Some of these still have broken regex’s but to add them, you’ll need to create a `.nanorc` file in your home directory, and add something like the following to it:

```
include /usr/share/nano/python.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/sh.nanorc
```

Add an include for all desired syntax highlighters. That’s it, restart your terminal.